# Erro ao popular SELECT - Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql

Não estou consegui popular meu select.

Segue abaixo meu código:

```
 <select>
            <option>Selecione</option>

            <?php while($serv = mysql_fetch_array(getAllServicos())) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $serv['Codigo'] ?>"><?php echo $serv['Descricao'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>

 </select>
```

Função getAllServicos():

```
function getAllServicos(){
$database = open_database(); 

$sql = "SELECT Codigo, Descricao FROM `tblservico` WHERE `Status` = true";
$result = $database->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $found = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
close_database($database);
return ($found);    
}
```

Erro:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAllServicos()` retorna uma array com os resultados do banco de dados, não faz sentido passar ele para a função legada `mysql_fetch_array()`. Pode passar direto em um foreach:

```
<?php foreach(getAllServicos() as $serv) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $serv['Codigo'] ?>"><?php echo $serv['Descricao'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

No `printf()` style ;)

```
<?php
    foreach(getAllServicos() as $serv) {
        printf('<option value="%s"> %s </option>', $serv['Codigo'], $serv['Descricao']);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado.